# Uploading to Amazon S3 gives 403 error - following example photo album guide

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a simple image to a S3 bucket, I always get a `403` error when try to upload, but list and createAlbum methods works.

I've followed this guide: [Uploading Photos to Amazon S3 from a Browser - AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

Since the upload of the tutorial don't work for me I've tried to use the `S3.upload` method without success as follow:

```
    S3.upload({
      Key: 'my-album/aqui.png',
      Body: file,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Bucket: SOUNDS_BUCKET_NAME
      }, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
          alert('fail')
        } else {
          alert('Successfully Uploaded!');
        }
      }
    );
```

I believe this error was a config on my S3 or my identity pool, but the config is the same as the tutorial:

CORS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Cognito:
[image]

S3:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you understand what a 403 error means?

Comment: https://http.cat/403

Comment: Yes I know, the point is that I don't know where else I should change permissions on aws to grant upload.

Answer (score 0):

This is Node.js code to upload files to S3.

### Setting up the Environment

#### AWS Credentials

To get started you need to generate the *AWS Security Key Access Credentials* first. To do so login to your *AWS Management Console*.

Click on your username:

[image]

Select *Access Keys* -> *Create New Access Key*:

[image]

After that you can either copy the *Access Key ID* and *Secret Access Key* from this window or you can download it as a `.CSV` file:

[image]

#### Creating an S3 Bucket

Now let's create a AWS S3 Bucket with proper access. We can do this using the AWS management console or by using Node.js.

To create an S3 bucket using the management console, go to the S3 service by selecting it from the service menu:

[image]

Select *"Create Bucket"* and enter the name of your bucket and the region that you want to host your bucket. If you already know from which region the majority of your users will come from, it's wise to select a region as close to their's as possible. This will ensure that the files from the server will be served in a more optimal timeframe.

The name you select for your bucket should be a unique name among all AWS users, so try a new one if the name is not available:

[image]

Follow through the wizard and configure permissions and other setting per your requirements.

To create the bucket using Node.js, we'll first have to set up our development environment.

#### Development Environment

Get started with our example by configuring a new Node.js project:

```
$ npm init
```

To start using any AWS Cloud Services in Node.js, we have to install the *AWS SDK* (System Development Kit).

Install it using your preferred package manager - we'll use `npm`:

```
$ npm i --save aws-sdk
```

### Implementation

#### Creating an S3 Bucket

If you have already created a bucket manually, you may skip this part. But if not, let's create a file, say, `create-bucket.js` in your project directory.

Import the `aws-sdk` library to access your S3 bucket:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

Now, let's define three constants to store `ID`, `SECRET`, and `BUCKET_NAME`. These are used to identify and access our bucket:

```
// Enter copied or downloaded access ID and secret key here
const ID = '';
const SECRET = '';

// The name of the bucket that you have created
const BUCKET_NAME = 'test-bucket';
```

Now we need to initialize the S3 interface by passing our access keys:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: ID,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET
});
```

<sub>**Source:** [Uploading Files to AWS S3 with Node.js](https://stackabuse.com/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-with-node-js/)</sub>